# Counting ways to select numbers from N lists

Tags: c++, algorithm

Given N lists which can have numbers between 1 to 100.

I want the numbers of ways to select numbers ,one from each of the different lists without allowing repetition.

Note : Two ways are different if any of the number selected is different.

Example :

```
List 1 : 5, 100, 1
List 2 : 2
List 3 : 5, 100
List 4 : 2, 5, 100
```

As I want to select 1 number from each,without repetition.

Answer in this case will be : 2 (1,2,5,100 and 1,2,100,5).

**My Approach :**  I tried solving it using principle of inclusion and exclusion.But how to find all intersections ?

I was thinking can it be solved using matching while taking lists in 1 set and corresponding mapping numbers in other.?

N can be upto 10 and each of the list can have numbers between 1-100 .

Also each list will have a number only once in it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a implementation of the proposed algorithm of @robertking

Notes:

- Using a `std::vector<bool>` for storage the already used numbers (are optimized for storage the bool as bits in most implementation of the STL).
- Using `cache` variable (Dynamic Programming) to speed up big search with previous obtained results.
- Use `TRACE` define to print the solutions or not.

Code (Tested in GCC 4.9.0 with C++11 in Windows):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

#define TRACE

typedef std::vector<bool> used_numbers_t;
typedef std::vector<int> list_t;
typedef std::vector<list_t> lists_t;

typedef std::map<std::pair<used_numbers_t, unsigned int>, int> cache_t;
cache_t cache;

long solve(used_numbers_t& used_numbers, const lists_t& lists, list_t& generated_solution, unsigned int list_idx = 0, int solutions = 0) {
    if (list_idx == lists.size()) {
#ifdef TRACE
        for (auto gs : generated_solution) {
            std::cout << gs << ",";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
#endif
        return solutions + 1;
    }

    auto key = std::make_pair(used_numbers, list_idx);
    auto it = cache.find(key);
    if (it != cache.cend()) {
        return it->second;
    }

    long actual_solutions = 0;
    auto& processing_list = lists[list_idx];
    for (unsigned int idx = 0; idx < processing_list.size(); idx++) {
        if (!used_numbers[processing_list[idx] - 1]) {
            used_numbers[processing_list[idx] - 1] = true;
#ifdef TRACE
            generated_solution.push_back(processing_list[idx]);
#endif

            actual_solutions += solve(used_numbers, lists, generated_solution, list_idx + 1, solutions);

#ifdef TRACE
            generated_solution.pop_back();
#endif
            used_numbers[processing_list[idx] - 1] = false;
        }
    }

    cache.insert(std::make_pair(key, actual_solutions));

    return solutions + actual_solutions;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    lists_t lists{{5, 100, 1}, {2}, {5, 100}, {2, 5, 100}};

    used_numbers_t used_numbers(100);
    list_t generated_solution;
    long solutions = solve(used_numbers, lists, generated_solution);
    std::cout << "The total number of solutions is: " << solutions << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Obtained Output:

```
1,2,5,100,
1,2,100,5,
The total number of solutions is: 2
```

Comment: Can you tell about its complexity?I think its inefficient approach and can be further optimised

Comment: I don't known the exact Big-O complexity, but the Dynamic Programming speed up really good, for example with the list that you proposed when analyzing (that is a really small example) taking `5 from 1`, `2 from 2` and `100 from 3` the value of how many solutions are found with this preselected is saved, and when taking `100 from 1`, `2 from 2` and `5 from 3` you already have how many solutions are because is in the same state as the first example. I recommend you, taking a good look at Dynamic Programming.

Comment: But i think some cases are calulcuated that are of no use and its pretty much close to a brute force type solution.Can their be some better approach?I think in worst case it will be going to O(N!)*100 which means as N can be 10 so pretty large value

Comment: All the cases calculated could be beneficial even if the solutions obtained with that pre-selection is 0 (even this case allow you to not continue processing when this pre-selection is found again). The worst case scenario is that you could not pre-select the same numbers from the same lists collection in more that one form in this case you would need to iterate through all the combinations. Profiled with a complex input or post the complex input data.